# How can I use FOR LOOP for date in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am new in oracle .
MY code is :

```
  SELECT a.ledger_code,
         a.ref_cur_id,
         a.ref_branch,
         a.balance,
         NVL (b.ledger_code, a.ledger_code),
         NVL (b.ref_cur_id, a.ref_cur_id),
         NVL (b.ref_branch, a.ref_branch),
         NVL (b.balance, a.balance)
    FROM (SELECT *
            FROM tbl_ledger_input
           WHERE eff_date = '06-APR-21') a
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                      FROM tbl_ledger_input
                     WHERE eff_date = '07-APR-21') b
            ON     a.ledger_code = b.ledger_code
               AND a.ref_cur_id = b.ref_cur_id
               AND a.ref_branch = b.ref_branch
   WHERE b.ledger_code IS NULL
ORDER BY a.ledger_code,
         a.ref_cur_id,
         a.ref_branch,
         b.ledger_code,
         b.ref_cur_id,
         b.ref_branch;
```

I want instead of date use a variable but I cant define I  as date for loop.

I want date for startdate 04-APR-21 and enddate 08-APR-21

please help me

my sample is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjruO.png)

How can use for loop for date in oracle

Comment: Why do you need a loop - can't you change your where clause to be `where eff_date >= date '2021-04-06' and eff_date < date '2021-04-09'` ? I'm not sure why that even needs to be a subquery. It's unclear what the logic is. Your sample seems to be a single line of output; base data from the tables would be more helpful, and as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Is your image description representing the sample data or result (it looks like result of your sql) - if it is result then where are sample data?  - if it is sample data then what is your expected result? What's the logic for getting the result (?) from sample data (?) ???

Comment: @d r  can I have your email ? or linkdin ?it s result . I cant good speak English but I Need
your help

Comment: @sami Sorry, but no, it would be against the rules. You could edit your question to define a few sample data rows and to show the expected result with some basic logic behind it. Both, sample data and result could be imagined not real.... And if the language is problem then do it without explanation of logic - just data and expected result - someone will got it, I'm sure...

Comment: @d r
thanks a lot . I didn't know it was against the rules. Thank you for telling me. Yes, I will definitely try to edit my question, maybe I will get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you saw what Alex commented.

Anyway: as question states "**How can I use FOR LOOP for date in oracle**", here are a few options you might consider.

Setting environment (you don't have to do that):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> set serveroutput on
```

This is a FOR loop which uses `DATE` datatype *boundaries*, and it doesn't work (I guess that's why you opened the question):

```
SQL> begin
  2    for i in date '2023-02-15' .. date '2023-02-20' loop
  3      dbms_output.put_line(i);
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /
  for i in date '2023-02-15' .. date '2023-02-20' loop
           *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 12:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

---

One option is to convert `date` datatype into a `number`; first `to_char` it to appropriate format (e.g. `yyyymmdd`):

```
SQL> begin
  2    for i in to_number(to_char(date '2023-02-15', 'yyyymmdd')) ..
  3             to_number(to_char(date '2023-02-20', 'yyyymmdd'))
  4    loop
  5      dbms_output.put_line(i ||'; '|| to_date(to_char(i), 'yyyymmdd'));
  6    end loop;
  7  end;
  8  /
20230215; 15.02.2023
20230216; 16.02.2023
20230217; 17.02.2023
20230218; 18.02.2023
20230219; 19.02.2023
20230220; 20.02.2023

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

Another option is to convert `date` value into Julian date. What's that? It is a 7-digit number which represents number of days since 31st of December 4712 B.C. If you don't really care about what it is, but only need to use *something* in `FOR` loop, that could also be one way to do it:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for i in to_number(to_char(date '2023-02-15', 'J')) ..
  3             to_number(to_char(date '2023-02-20', 'J'))
  4    loop
  5      dbms_output.put_line(i ||'; '|| to_date(to_char(i), 'J'));
  6    end loop;
  7  end;
  8  /
2459991; 15.02.2023
2459992; 16.02.2023
2459993; 17.02.2023
2459994; 18.02.2023
2459995; 19.02.2023
2459996; 20.02.2023

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle Database 21c you can specify the data type for index variables. The upper and lower bounds must still evaluate to numbers though.

So if you want to loop through a series of dates you can do using a `repeat ... while` loop:

```
begin
  for i date in date '2023-02-15', 
    repeat i + 1
    while i <= date '2023-02-20' 
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line ( 'Val = ' || i );
  end loop;
end;
/

Val = 15-FEB-2023 00:00
Val = 16-FEB-2023 00:00
Val = 17-FEB-2023 00:00
Val = 18-FEB-2023 00:00
Val = 19-FEB-2023 00:00
Val = 20-FEB-2023 00:00
```

Comment: thank you but I think cause I could speak English , I do not explain correctly my main problem .